# rails custom library recoding with dry way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, gibbon

I have this mailchimp.rb file but I think it is not efficient.

```
class MailchimpAdapter
  class << self


    def remove_from_mailchimp_list(user, bucket_id) 
      connection = Gibbon.new
      lists = connection.lists
      begin
        connection.list_unsubscribe({:id => lists["data"][user_type_id]["id"], :email_address => user.email, :delete_member => true, :send_goodbye => false, :send_notify => false})
      rescue Exception => ex
      end
    end

    def add_to_mailchimp_list(user, bucket_id)
      connection = Gibbon.new
      lists = connection.lists
      begin
        connection.list_subscribe({:id => lists["data"][user_type_id]["id"], :email_address => user.email, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => user.user_name, :LNAME => ""}, :double_optin => false})
      rescue Exception => ex
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Is there any better way to code this class ? Because I repeat this part

```
connection = Gibbon.new
lists = connection.lists
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
class MailchimpAdapter
  class << self

    def remove_from_mailchimp_list(user, bucket_id) 
      list_operation do |connection, lists|
        connection.list_unsubscribe({:id => lists["data"][user_type_id]["id"], :email_address => user.email, :delete_member => true, :send_goodbye => false, :send_notify => false})
      end
    end

    def add_to_mailchimp_list(user, bucket_id)
      list_operation do |connection, lists|
        connection.list_subscribe({:id => lists["data"][user_type_id]["id"], :email_address => user.email, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => user.user_name, :LNAME => ""}, :double_optin => false})
      end
    end

    private

    def list_operation
      connection = Gibbon.new
      lists = connection.lists
      begin
        yield(connection, lists)
      rescue Exception => ex
      end
    end

  end
end
```